# Add objects with random variables using a loop

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program where I ask to the user how many persons he wants to implement in this world. Afterwards, I would like as many person objects as the user answered. I defined a person class with a person constructor containing all person variables ( + getters/setters). After this, I tried to create a loop to assign values to my variables (most of them happen random). Currently, I set the number of instances I want to create to 20 (arbitrary).

```
This is my person class 


public class Person implements Item {
    public static final int MAX_AGE = 70;
    public static final int MAX_SEX_APPEAL = 10;
    public static final int MAX_AGRESSION_LEVEL = 10;
    public static final int MAX_STRENGTH = 10;
    private int id; 
    private int age; 
    private boolean gender; 
    private int sexAppeal; 
    private int agressionLevel; 
    private int strength; 
    private boolean isAlive;

    public Person (int id, int age, boolean gender, int sexAppeal, int agressionLevel, int strength, boolean isAlive){
        this.setId(id);
        this.setAge(age); 
        this.setGender(gender);
        this.setSexAppeal(sexAppeal); 
        this.setAgressionLevel(agressionLevel);
        this.setStrength(strength);
        this.setAlive(isAlive);
    }

    void getBorn () {
        isAlive = true; 
        age = 0;

        // a new people is born 
        // age = 0 
        // other variables: random 
    }

    void die () { 
        isAlive = false;
        // people die when they reach the max age 
        // people die when being on the same cell as vulcanos
        // people can be murdered 
        // setAlive = false 
    }

    void murder () { 
        // when 2 people with min agression level on the same land ==> weakest one dies 

    }

    void move () {
        // method to make people move 
        // random (only to adjucant fields) 
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public boolean isGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(boolean gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public int getSexAppeal() {
        return sexAppeal;
    }

    public void setSexAppeal(int sexAppeal) {
        this.sexAppeal = sexAppeal;
    }

    public int getAgressionLevel() {
        return agressionLevel;
    }

    public void setAgressionLevel(int agressionLevel) {
        this.agressionLevel = agressionLevel;
    }

    public int getStrength() {
        return strength;
    }

    public void setStrength(int strength) {
        this.strength = strength;
    }

    public boolean isAlive() {
        return isAlive;
    }

    public void setAlive(boolean isAlive) {
        this.isAlive = isAlive;
    }



}
```

And this is my "test class" where I try to create 20 instances :

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i ++) {
            Person person(i) = new Person();
            person.setId(i);
            person.setAge(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, Person.MAX_AGE + 1));
            person.setGender((Math.random() < 0.5));
            person.setSexAppeal(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, Person.MAX_SEX_APPEAL + 1));
            person.setAgressionLevel(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, Person.MAX_SEX_APPEAL + 1));
            person.setStrength(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, Person.MAX_SEX_APPEAL + 1));
            person.setAlive(true);


        }


    }
}
```

However, I am getting the following error at this line

```
Person person(i) = new Person();
```

- The constructor Person () is undefined
- Type mismatch: cannot convert from Person to int
  I understand those errors but I don't know another way to become to the result I want to achieve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make a list and just add the created persons to it.

```
public class test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>(); // create a list to store the generated persons
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      Person person = new Person(); // generate a person
      person.setId(i);
      person.setAge(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, Person.MAX_AGE + 1));
      person.setGender((Math.random() < 0.5));
      person.setSexAppeal(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, Person.MAX_SEX_APPEAL + 1));
      person.setAgressionLevel(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, Person.MAX_SEX_APPEAL + 1));
      person.setStrength(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, Person.MAX_SEX_APPEAL + 1));
      person.setAlive(true);

      persons.add(person); /// add the generated person to the list

    }


  }
}
```

Also if you want to call the **Person** constructor without parameters the class must have a constructor that takes no parameters.

```java
public Person() {}
```

Comment: And create the empty constructor for `Person` !

Comment: Indeed! I will edit the answer. Thanks for spotting it.

Comment: So I can just adjust my person class by adding a new constructor "Public Person () { } " and then it should work?

Comment: Should I remove the other constructor in the person class then?

Comment: you can have both of them, you just need an empty constructor if you want to call **new Person()**

Comment: @StievieG thanks for the correction, I just got too used to responding javascript questions. :)

Comment: Thank you very much! One last question, is there a way to print out an overview of all objects I created? I think I can't use a tostring method since I'm working with arraylists

Comment: you can iterate over the array and print them to screen. Overriding the **toString** method in Person will help make it prettier.